# build cmd into Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i was wondering if you could have the comand prompt box pop into the Tkinter window when you start the program? Some thing like:

```
from Tkinter import *
admin = Tk()
cmd = Cmd(admin)
cmd.pack()
admin.mainloop()
```

I'm on windows

Comment: I really don't think something like this can be done, I know Tkinter can tap into certain OS specific windows, like color selector or file window, but I doubt there's a way to embed the console. Maybe if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish we can better help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any built in console widget. It may be possible to whip up a custom one using the Tkinter Text widget. However, that would take a bit of effort/time.

Another possible option is simply have your program launch command prompt.

Two different ways to launch command prompt on a Windows machine.

```
import subprocess, os

subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')

os.system("cmd.exe")
```

**EDIT:**

Unforunetly I don't believe there is any built in widget like that. However I thought of another possible solution, check out the code for the [IDLE GUI](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html), it has a console and the GUI portion is entirley written using Tkinter. So you may be able to utelize that code.

Comment: No. You know when you start a python program on windows and a command promkpt like window comes up along with your Tkinter window? i want the cmd like window to be put into the tkinter window or at least customize where the cmd like window will pop up?

Answer (score 4):

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/CmdTkHere is what you want, this is not just opening a cmd window. its embedding cmd.exe into a Tkinter.Frame. And a note here if you rename the python script to ".pyw" extension, the console will be hidden. Except for in a virtual environment's.

Comment: Dead link: any idea where I might find this?

Comment: @ajsp, take a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170310214048/http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/CmdTk